# Trouble in understanding why function is constant in a given domain

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, mathematical-physics

**Definition** The group of unitary operators $u(\theta)$ on $L^2(\mathbb R^3)$ given by $(u(\theta)\Phi)(r) =\Phi(\theta) \equiv e^{\frac{3\theta}{2}}\Phi(e^\theta r)$
is called the group of dilation operators on  $\mathbb R^3.$

Let $H$ be a compact operator and $R(z) \equiv(H-z)^{-1}$ the resolvent.
Define $R(z,\theta)$ by  $R(z,\theta) \equiv u(\theta)R(z)u(\theta)^{-1}$. Let us define also $\mathcal O \equiv \{\theta \in \mathbb C: (u(\theta)\Phi)(r)$ for $\theta \in \mathbb R$ has an analytic continuation $ \}$

In this article [A Class of Analytic Perturbations
for One-body Schrδdinger Hamiltonians](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cmp/1103857512) they were able to show that the function $\Psi_z(\theta)=(\phi(\theta)
,R(z,\theta)\phi(\theta))$ is meromorphic in $z$ for $z \in \mathcal C^{++} \equiv \{z \in \mathbb C : Im \ z > 0 ,\ Re \ z > 0 \} $ and $\theta \in \mathcal O^\epsilon \equiv \{\theta \in \mathcal O: Im \ \theta > \epsilon \}$

Now since for $\theta \in \mathbb R,\ u(\theta)$ is unitary we have that

$\Psi_z \equiv (\Phi,R(z)\Phi)=\Psi_z(\theta)$

from this they claim that $\Psi_z(\theta)$ that for fixed $z \in \mathcal C^{++}$ and $\theta \in \mathcal O^\epsilon$ the function $\Psi_z(\theta)$ is constant in $\theta$.

My question is why is  $\Psi_z(\theta)$  constant for fixed $z \in \mathcal C^{++}$ and $\theta \in \mathcal O^\epsilon$ ?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, they have shown:

1. That $\Phi_z(\theta)$ is meromorphic in a region containing part of the real line.
2. That $\Phi_z(\theta)$ is constant on the real line (using unitarity of $u(\theta)$ for real $\theta$).

Hence by analytic continuation, $\Phi_z(\theta)$ must be constant over the entire region connected to the real line where it is meromorphic.

Comment: So if a meromorphic function is constant in a interval  than i will be constant in all its domain?

Comment: @amiltonmoreira In all of the domain which is connected to the interval, yes.

Comment: I gave a proof as question  here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3505785/prove-that-if-a-meromorphic-function-is-constant-in-an-open-region-then-it-is-co

Comment: would you check it if it is correct please?

Comment: @amiltonmoreira Yes, your proof looks basically correct.  It all follows from uniqueness of analytic continuation.

Comment: So every meromorphic function is of the form $F=\frac{f}{g}$ with $f$ and $g$ holomorphic

Comment: @amiltonmoreira Yes.  The wikipedia page on meromorphic functions says so explicitly in the second paragraph: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meromorphic_function