Applying the Identity Theorem to Analytic Functions Agreeing on 1D Curves
I'm working through a complex analysis problem and have encountered a problem that I'm struggling to understand. The context involves two meromorphic functions, g and h, which are given on the unit circle that $h(z)=g(z)$ when  $|z|=1$
Since g and h are meromorphic, g - h should be analytical around $|z|=1$ and vanishes at |z| = 1. Does this imply that g = h is everywhere, not only the special case of |z| = 1
Note: The Identity Theorem would require that $g−h$ is analytic and vanishes on an open set that includes points other than those on the unit circle to conclude that g and h are identical on their entire domain of analyticity. Since this condition is not mentioned in the text, is it ok to conclude f = g with the information given above?
For further information of the question I am working on: Particular holomorphic mappings of the Riemann sphere to itself

Perhaps look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3505785/27978

@copper.hat Thanks for the help! I looked at it and it seems to deal with open sets, in which the identity theorem is true. However, if I am to deal with non-open sets in this case (overlaps over 1D manifold) I am not sure if the same reasoning still applies.

The identity theorem only requires equality on a set with at least one accumulation point in the domain.  Any curve will do.

By Identity theorem, we can see that $g,h$ has finite poles inside the unit disk. Let's denote these poles of $g$ and $h$ by $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ with order $m_1,\ldots,m_n$, respectively. Then
$$g_1=\prod_{i=1}^n(z-a_i)^{m_i}g(z), \quad h_1=\prod_{i=1}^n(z-a_i)^{m_i}h(z),$$
are analytic functions on the unit disk and $g_1=h_1$ on $\partial B(0,1)$. Thus $|g_1-h_1|=0$ on the boundary, which implies that $g_1=h_1$ on the closed unit disk by Maximum modulus theorem. Clearly this shows $g=h$ on the open unit disk - except at the poles. If a pole is the common pole of $h,g$ then we are done. Otherwise,assume that the pole $a_1$ of $g$ is not a pole of $h$. But this is impossible since $g$ is unbounded near $a_1$ while $h$ is bounded, and we knew that $g=h$ near $a_1$.
